# How can I detect network connectivity in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I detect network connectivity in Windows Phone 7? Is there a simple API for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easier fast way to detect whether the (Windows Phone 7) device has an internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680374/is-there-an-easier-fast-way-to-detect-whether-the-windows-phone-7-device-has-an)

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a valid, good question - just a dupe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it :-P

`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable(`);

Thanks guys you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: It always return true, why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged.aspx) event in **System.Net.NetworkInformation** namesapce.

Checkout [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chkoenig/archive/2009/03/22/detecting-network-status-in-silverlight-3.aspx) blog for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the 
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface class
as provided the below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable`

in `Microsoft.Phone.Net namespace`